# Get return value from setTimeout

Tags: javascript, return, settimeout, return-value

I just want to get the return value from `setTimeout` but what I get is a whole text format of the function?

```js
function x () {
    setTimeout(y = function () {
        return 'done';
    }, 1000);
    return y;
}

console.log(x());
```

Comment: your syntax is like that, it will return function only.

Comment: do you want "done" to be returned? How can you return a result of function, which will be called 1000 ms later?

Comment: Timeouts are asynchronous, so you can't return from them. (well, you can, but the return value is going nowhere)

Comment: better to get a callback in function `x` and call that function with done.

Comment: +1 @IvanKuckir, i admit

Comment: `const x = async (waitMs) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('done'), waitMs));`  `console.log(await x(1000));`

Comment: `setTimeout()` returns an id number already. This number can be applied to the `clearTimeout()` method to cancel that timer.

Comment: I'd say this question is not a duplicate, even though its solution is already elsewhere. There are still a lot of users that see `setTimeout` as an apart operator and coming here can be an eye opener, a gentle nudge towards thinking in promises.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You need to use Promises for this. They are [available in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) but can be polyfilled [quite easily](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise):

```
function x() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       resolve('done!');
     });
   });
}

x().then((done) => {
  console.log(done); // --> 'done!'
});
```

With `async`/`await` in ES2017 it becomes nicer if inside an `async` function:

```
async function() {
  const result = await x();
  console.log(result); // --> 'done!';
}
```

Comment: actually the `done` in my example was a promise that needs to be returned inside a setTimeout..because i cant get the returned deferred.resolve() inside setTimeout. how would it be? thank you

Comment: Can you post a clearer example of your code in the question?

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 18):

You can't get a return value from the function you pass to `setTimeout`.

The function that called `setTimeout` (`x` in your example) will finish executing and return before the function you pass to `setTimeout` is even called.

Whatever you want to do with the value you get, you need to do it from the function you pass to `setTimeout`.

In your example, that would be written as:

```
function x () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("done");
    }, 1000);
}

x();
```

Answer (score 6):

Better to take a callback for function `x` and whatever task you want to perform after that timeout send in that callback.

```
function x (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback("done");
    }, 1000);
}

x(console.log.bind(console)); //this is special case of console.log
x(alert)
```

Comment: Bare in mind, that this will not await after the function call, so it might actually not happen. For example add process.exit, after calling x and "done" will be never done.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of Promise and setTimeOut like the example below

```
let f1 = function(){
    return new Promise(async function(res,err){
        let x=0;
        let p = new Promise(function(res,err){
            setTimeout(function(){
                x= 1;
                res(x);
            },2000)
        })
        p.then(function(x){
            console.log(x);
            res(x);
        })


    });
}
```

Answer (score -6):

I think you want have flag to know event occured or no. setTimeout not return a value. you can use a variable to detect event occured or no

```
var y="notdone";
   setTimeout(function () {
         y="done";
    }, 1000);
```

You can access variable y after timeout occured to know done or not