# function call on object with delay

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this code return each employees name.

```js
var company = {
    employees: [
        {
            name: "doug"
        },
        {
            name: "AJ"
        }
    ],
    getName: function(employee){
        return employee.name
    },
    getNames: function(){
        return this.employees.map(this.getName)
    },
    delayedGetNames: function(){
        setTimeout(this.getNames,500)
    }
}

console.log(company.delayedGetNames());
```

However, when I run the code I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

I have tried doing

```
setTimeout(this.getNames.bind(this),500)
```

I just get undefined returned to me.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `setTimeout` has no return value. Your `console.log` will always return undefined. You need to use Promises.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get return value from setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928846/get-return-value-from-settimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, using `Promise`, you could write something like this:

```js
var company = {
    employees: [
        {
            name: "doug"
        },
        {
            name: "AJ"
        }
    ],
    getName: function(employee){
        return employee.name
    },
    getNames: function(){
        return this.employees.map(this.getName)
    },
    delayedGetNames: function() {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(this.getNames()), 1000));
    }
}

company.delayedGetNames().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a callback to your function in order to get the names.

```js
var company = {
    employees: [
        {
            name: "doug"
        },
        {
            name: "AJ"
        }
    ],
    getName: function(employee){
        return employee.name
    },
    getNames: function(){
        return this.employees.map(this.getName)
    },
    delayedGetNames: function(cb){
        setTimeout(()=>cb(this.getNames()),500)
    }
}
company.delayedGetNames(names => console.log(names))
```

Answer (score 1):

With few tricks and `getters`

```
var company = {
    employees: [
        {
            name: "doug"
        },
        {
            name: "AJ"
        }
    ],
    getName: function(employee){
        return employee.name
    },
    get getNames(){
        console.log(this.employees.map(x => this.getName(x)));
    },
    get delayedGetNames(){
        setTimeout(this.getNames,500)
    }
}

console.log(company.delayedGetNames);
```