# Why await does not wait for setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, async-await

Trying to learn async/await, The below code, awaits on `getUserName()` to return userName after 2s. `hasUser` (returns a promise) then just logs the received username.

The problem is `console.log(msg)` inside the then method logs `undefined`.

```
function getUserName() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return 'Appu'
    },2000)
}

var hasUser= async() => {
        var a = await getUserName()
        return a
    }

hasUser().then((msg) => {
    console.log(msg)
})
```

Not sure what is the problem here. Appreciate explaining what actually is going on here.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get return value from setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928846/get-return-value-from-settimeout)

Comment: getUserName is not returning a Promise. And setTimeout doesn't return a promise, so you'll have to translate from its callback pattern into a promise. The accepted answer on Scott's link shows how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

`hasUser` does not return a promise. You try to `await getUserName()` but that doesn't return a promise either. If you want to `await getUsername()` you need to make `getUserName` return a promise

```
function getUserName() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('Appu')
       },2000)
    })
}
```