# Get value from setTimout inside a forEach

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, settimeout

I have now spent several hours here reading through the solutions to this problem, like this:
[Get return value from setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928846/get-return-value-from-settimeout#24929146)

But I can't find any solution for my problem to get the removeCount value. I also tried to add a Promise, but I don't know how to do it with the increment.

```js
async function removeNeedlessNotifications(mutations) {
    const getResult = async () => {
        let removeCount = 0;
        mutations.forEach((v) =>
            v.addedNodes.forEach((v, i) =>
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (notificationFilter(v)) {
                        v.querySelector("div.activity-remove.js-remove").click();
                        removeCount++;
                    }
                }, i * 100)
            )
        );
        return removeCount;
    };

    return await getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `for` loops instead so you can `await` inside, and it becomes trivial:

```
async function removeNeedlessNotifications(mutations) {
    let removeCount = 0;
    for (const mutation of mutations) {
        for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
            if (notificationFilter(node)) {
                node.querySelector("div.activity-remove.js-remove").click();
                removeCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return removeCount;
}
```

This will return a Promise that resolves to the number of divs clicked.

Comment: Very interesting. But now I have the problem that it returns only a Promise. For that I would have used the following:
`const notificationsObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
const removedNeedlessNotifications = await removeNeedlessNotifications(mutations);
}`
But I only get the text back. I'm so bad with async/await :(

Comment: You need to consume the Promise. Either make the callback async so you can await it, or call `.then` on the Promise.

Comment: Little question is there a difference between `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));` and `await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));`?

Comment: No, those are exactly the same. Parentheses are optional around arrow function arguments when there's exactly one argument.

Comment: Just to see how to solve the problem with async/await, I did it like this:
`async () => {
            console.log(await removeNeedlessNotifications(mutations));
        };` but I didn't get something back. What is missing?

Comment: This way it works: `(async () => {
            console.log(await removeNeedlessNotifications(mutations));
        })();`
But don't know why and don't know how to search this kind of syntax. Don't want to post a duplicate question.

Comment: You don't need to make an async IIFE (which takes a bit of annoying syntax noise), all you need is to consume the Promise. `removeNeedlessNotifications(mutations).then(console.log)` should work

Comment: at CertainPerformance:
That was my first solution. But in articles and videos about Promise and async/await it was often said that async/await was the syntactically superior version of the .then solution.

Comment: It seems that in my first version my function was just not executed. I wonder if there is a useful case for this. At least my IDE did not criticize the syntax.

Comment: Async functions are good when you have *at least two* Promises to consume, IMO. Otherwise, I think using `.then` makes the syntax easier.